# Replacing COMMA with EQUALOP ML error

Tags: sml, ml

```
val x =10;
fun power (x:int, y:int) =
    if y=1
    then x
else 
x * power (x,y-1)
val z = power 2,3
```

It gives me an error Replacing COMMA with EQUALOP . I dont understand whats the error in the code ??

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around the argument to `power` in the declaration of `z`:

```
val z = power (2,3);
```